# Need sample problems for hands-on

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stl, polymorphism

I have been working with C++ for a few years now and have got good theoretical knowledge on the matter (I think).
However I've been missing involvement in good projects, sort of projects that really gets one going on the technologies.
So I intend to work on my own to get some good grip on C++ and related technologies.
'Have started with a sample projects such as designing and coding a telephone directory.

Please suggest similar projects/problems that test knowledge about C++ , all aspects of the language such as using STL containers/algorithms, polymorphism, as well as designing (design patterns).

Comment: Going through the c++-faq-lite will make you familiar with common issues: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link to test you c/c++ skills and really tough stuff.

http://www.tenouk.com/cpluspluscompetitioncontest.html

Book on **Data Structures, Algorithms, And Applications In C++  by Sartaj Sahni**
has really challenging problems sets and you will enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

Project Euler is a large collection of mathematical problems, most of which are most effectively solved by writing small programs.

Doing these will not expose you to the whole technological breadth of C++ but could be part of a self-study program around algorithms, performance, logic and of course mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

Code katas!
Modular progressively more difficult sets of questions that allow a gradual introduction into the more esoteric uses of the language. Various sites have their own question sets.

Parashift C++ FAQs are useful, and so is the C++ idioms wiki - they offer a more overall shaping of design - concentrating on efficiency and correctness.